# openxlsx currency style - Is there a rounding option?

Tags: r, excel, xlsx, openxlsx

The `createStyle` function in the `openxlsx` package has an argument `numFmt`, which allows you to create an excel format to be applied to specific cells in a .xlsx file. You can round values by specifying `numFmt = '0'`, and you can apply a currency format by specifying `numFmt = "CURRENCY"`.

Is there a way to specify a rounded currency format? 
I've tried the following:

- Rounding the values in the data frame doesn't work, because the excel
  cells still display the cents e.g. `$103.00`.
- `numfmt = 'CURRENCY0'` does not work

If not, is there another package which allows you to specify the formats of excel cells, and allows rounding of currency-formatted cells?

Edit:

This gives me what I wanted (Currency format, with commas, no cents)

```
createStyle(numFmt="$0,0")
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set `numFmt="$0"` to get rounded currency values. For example:

```
library(openxlsx)

mtcars$hp = 100 * mtcars$hp

wb = createWorkbook()
sht = addWorksheet(wb, "test")
writeData(wb, sht, mtcars)

sty1 = createStyle(numFmt="$0")
sty2 = createStyle(numFmt="$0.00")
sty3 = createStyle(numFmt="$0,0.00")

addStyle(wb, sht, sty1, rows=2:(nrow(mtcars)+1), cols=1)
addStyle(wb, sht, sty2, rows=2:(nrow(mtcars)+1), cols=5)
addStyle(wb, sht, sty3, rows=2:(nrow(mtcars)+1), cols=4)

saveWorkbook(wb, "test.xlsx")
```

Here's what the resulting Excel file looks like:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Two questions: (1) How did you know this? Is there an explanation of all available formats somewhere? (2) This removes the commas. How can I keep the commas and still round?

Comment: I've added an example with a comma separator. How did I know this? I've never carefully studied the rules of Excel number formats, but over the years I've occasionally needed to create a custom format. As a result, I have a rough idea of how they work. The formats I created in my answer just seemed like the "natural" thing to do, and they turned out to work. If they hadn't worked, I would have Googled and figured out how to tweak them.

Comment: For an explanation of how to create your own custom formats, there are lots of web pages with examples. Google "Excel number formats" or "Excel custom number formats" (without the quotes) or something like that and you'll see a bunch of guides.

Comment: One additional note on custom number formats: I should have clarified that these formats are not special options limited to `openxlsx`. Rather, they are the standard Microsoft Office formatting codes, and `openxlsx` just allows you to use them within R to format data written to Excel files.

Answer (score 1):

just incase you want to format in other currencies, you could try this

style = createStyle(numFmt="[$CURRENCY SYMBOL]#,##0")

E.g

style = createStyle(numFmt="[$UGX]#,##0")